# including own published papers in answers

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Now that I am convinced that my post is not a 'homework' type, I am preparing an answer that will take some information from references found.  But, my question is, as it is relevant to my answer, is it allowable (or pretentious) to include a link to one of my own published papers?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/582/2451

Comment: jackpot! That and the answer below are what I am after - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

See [the relevant section of the FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/behavior)

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must [explicitly] disclose your affiliation in your answers. [E.g. it is not enough that your name is mentioned in the link.]

As long as your post doesn't look like one big advertisement or pitch for your work, and you disclose your affiliation, it's OK :)

Comment: that's a fair enough rule - any response would just touch on my paper, I now have found another reference that is a great one.

Comment: @DamienIgoe: Great :) Even if you have a better reference, it wouldn't hurt to mention your own paper in a footnote. If it's relevant there's no reason why it shouldn't get linked. As long as it's obvious that your answer isn't meant as a promotion

Comment: Thank you for this, I have made my post - the emphasis is on the 2 other excellent articles that I found, while following up the links given by krs013.  I included my article, only as it shows the response characteristics that I am describing.

Comment: @DamienIgoe: Good answer (+1). I always like answers full of links (as long as they have some content on their own). There wasn't any need to explicitly mention your lack of affiliation with Hamamatsu, but that's a trivial matter. A suggestion: You probably can make your answer meatier by including more details. Up to you, of course :)

Comment: meaty answers - now I am getting hungry.  Thank you for that, I will have a look over and see what I can add in.

Comment: I am the same, i like answers full of links.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with it. I would encourage you to make it clear on the post if you have written (or have other connections, i.e. personal, financial or otherwise, with) any of the resources you reference, but I would definitely encourage you to include any and all references you feel are relevant to the post.

That said, you should avoid self-promotion, and if it comes across as that then the community is likely to downvote you, as Manishearth points out.